# Mailman AND external mail service

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain

I have a virtual server (with a Plesk instance) and a domain, both from a hosting provider who also hosts an email service (on a central server) for the same domain (i.e. `info@mydomain.example`). I would like to keep the provider's email service AND use Mailman (via Plesk) for email lists (`mylist@mydomain.example` or, if necessary, `mylist@mysubdomain.mydomain.example`). How can I do that?

More specifically:

1. Do I need a subdomain or can I use my regular domain?
2. How do I configure my domain's DNS, especially the MX record(s)?